# Get the Max _id from ContentResolver from Contacts.CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I want to get the last added contact in the contacts and for getting that i want to pull the max _id of the contact. So here is my query that i want to realise:

```
AppMain.applicationContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
    new String[]{
            "MAX(" + ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + ") as max_id", 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
    }, 
    null, null, null);
```

But unfortunately i am getting this error:
Invalid column MAX(contact_id) as max_id

I tried removing the 'as max_id' but no luck.

Does any one know how to get the last added contact or get the max _id of the contact.

Answer (score 1):

This is not officially supported by Android's `ContentProvider` framework, especially if the Provider set the `strictProjectionMap` flag.

But this should work instead, it asks for all contacts sorted by contact-id, and limits the results to 1:

```
Cursor c = cr.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Contacts._ID }, null, null, Contacts._ID + "DESC LIMIT 1");
if (c != null && c.moveToNext()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "id is: " + c.getLong(0));
}
```